# How to read part of string in Python?

Tags: python, file

I have a database containing folders with files. I manage to read the files and get specific lines containing the `montage` word...

`montage = 0, FP1-F7: EEG FP1-REF --  EEG F7-REF

montage = 1, F7-T3:  EEG F7-REF  --  EEG T3-REF

montage = 2, T3-T5:  EEG T3-REF  --  EEG T5-REF

montage = 3, T5-O1:  EEG T5-REF  --  EEG O1-REF`

Now, I want to be able to extract what is between the comma and the double point (i.e. `FP1-F7`, `F7-T3`,...) but I don't know how to do ?

Moreover, why does the `print` command display lines with a "space" between (not shown below but real) ?

Comment: `print` appends a newline at the end by default, if you have a `\n` in your string, you'll have an empty line after the printed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the token you want (note: this works with the samples you provided, if there's other commas or colons before the points you show, this won't work):

```
def parse_line(line):
  start = line.find(',')
  end = line.find(':')
  return line[start+1:end].strip()
```

You can also do this with regex, but IMO for this scenario that's overkilling.

Getting the list of tokens then can be done with a list comprehension:

```
tokens = [parse_line(l) for l in lines]
```

where `lines` is the list of lines to parse (or, if you're reading from a text file, the file object itself)

Comment: I accept this one because it's more intuitive than using regex; thank you @GPhilo, it helps

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex.

```
import re
s = """montage = 0, FP1-F7: EEG FP1-REF --  EEG F7-REF
montage = 1, F7-T3:  EEG F7-REF  --  EEG T3-REF
montage = 2, T3-T5:  EEG T3-REF  --  EEG T5-REF
montage = 3, T5-O1:  EEG T5-REF  --  EEG O1-REF """

for i in s.splitlines():
    m = re.search(r",(.*?):", i)     #Get content between , and :
    if m:
        print(m.group(1).strip())
```

**Output:**

```
FP1-F7
F7-T3
T3-T5
T5-O1
```